# Как в aiogram 2 сделать оправку клавиатуры после каждого сообщения автоматически?

Tags: python, aiogram-2.x

Нужно, чтобы после каждого отправленного ботом сообщения выводилась одна и та же клавиатура автоматически. Как это сделать?